# Insert variables into JSON.dump

Tags: python

I can't find a simple example for this:

```
start="2001-02-03T04:05:06.000007Z",
end="2001-02-03T08:09:10+01:00",
files=["query.log"]

data=json.dumps(
    {
        "start": f'{start}',
        "end": f'{end}',
        "files": f'{files}',
    }
)
```

I get the error:

```
- Payload key `files`: Not a valid list.
```

Comment: I don't reproduce your error: `{"start": "('2001-02-03T04:05:06.000007Z',)", "end": "('2001-02-03T08:09:10+01:00',)", "files": "['query.log']"}`

Comment: Why do you use f-string ? just write `"files": files`

Comment: @Marius, `f'{files}'` generates the string representation of `files`, not exactly the same, but yes, it will generate a list which might be what is needed here

Comment: @MariusROBERT Amagawd that was embarrassing, worked when I removed the format `f{''}`. Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: "I get the error:" Where does this error come from? Please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages when posting, and explain the problem with proper context - see [mre]. The message that you show does not even look like a Python exception; it looks like it's coming from something else in the project that reads the data and expects to see something else. I shouldn't have to explain these things to a 10+ year user of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't use f-string here

```
start="2001-02-03T04:05:06.000007Z",
end="2001-02-03T08:09:10+01:00",
files=["query.log"]

data=json.dumps(
    {
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
        "files": files,
    }
)
```